# Does short-circuiting GPIO pins damage the Raspberry?

Tags: gpio, safety

Does accidently connecting the wrong GPIO pins damage the Raspberry Pi or is there some protection like a fuse?

Comment: There are no fuses there. But what part of the GPIO pins did you connect, in what way, wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Connecting the power and ground pins simultaneously, or the correct combination of GPIO and power or ground pins can fry not only the pin but the entire PI (GPIO voltage levels are 3.3 V and are not 5 V tolerant. There is no over-voltage protection on the board) . You may want to check out this article from the elinux wiki regarding [protecting the GPIO Pins](http://elinux.org/RPi_Tutorial_EGHS%3aGPIO_Protection_Circuits)

Comment: Thanks for clarification! Putting a zener diode and a resistor to the GPIO pins will at least help to keep calm when experimenting ;-)